# Non-standard special documentation blocks and doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm using a 3rd party API C sources where special documentation blocks are as following

```
/****************************************************************************************
 * @fn          fn
 *
 * @brief       brief
 *
 * @param       param
 *
 * @return      return
 ****************************************************************************************
 */
void fn(void)
{
 ...
}
```

Is there a way to convince Doxygen these are real special documentation blocks without modifying sources in order to match standard block (e.g. exactly two asterisks at block start)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see a problem here - the asterisks following the first two should be ignored by doxygen, no?

Comment: No, they aren't (see http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/docblocks.html). I'd like to configure Doxygen to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to create an input filter that replaces `/******` by `/**` and add that to the `INPUT_FILTER`
option in the configuration file. If you have the Unix command `sed` on your system, the following would do the trick:

```
INPUT_FILTER           = "sed -e 's|/\*\*\**|/**|g'"
```